# Complex type infer. Quite sure it's possible in TS, but

Tags: typescript, types, typescript-typings, typescript-generics

got a quite interesting problem I can't really solve.

I want to create a function what takes an object of functions, AND returns an object with the same keys but different return type (THE return type depends on the argument's value.

For example:

```
declare function add(a: number, b: number): number
declare function str(a: string, b: string): string

declare function createObject(obj)

const result = createObject({
   addFn: add,
   strFn: str
}) 

/*
   result's TYPE should equal:
   {
      addFn: [number, (a: number, b: number) => number],
      strFn: [string, (a: string, b: string) => string]
   }
*/
```

In my opinion this looks possible to solve, yet I am not sure how. The closest I could get to my resolution was the next lines:

```
type GenericHashTable<T> = { [key in keyof T]: T[key] };

function createAPI<T extends { [k: string]: any }>(fetchers: T) {
  const obj: GenericHashTable<T> = fetchers;
  return obj;
}
```

But this decl won't let me change the return type properly.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Looks like you just need the predefined `ReturnType` conditional type:

```
declare function add(a: number, b: number): number
declare function str(a: string, b: string): string

type GenericHashTable<T extends Record<keyof T, (...a: any[]) => any>> = { [key in keyof T]: [ReturnType<T[key]>, T[key]] };

declare function createAPI<T extends Record<keyof T, (...a: any[]) => any>>(fetchers: T): GenericHashTable<T>;

const result = createAPI({
   addFn: add,
   strFn: str
}) 

// Same as
const result: {
    addFn: [number, (a: number, b: number) => number];
    strFn: [string, (a: string, b: string) => string];
}
```

Comment: Wow... I didn't know about this Record. Tried the ReturnType in it self at first, but the compiler did not let me do that. A BIG THANKS man, been trying to figure out for a while how could I infer the right types. Love how smart TS can be with type inference :)